# blackberry10 c++ .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore, blackberry-10

I have a git repo with BB10 development using the C/C++ Native SDK. Do you have advice on the .gitignore file, or a template like the ones to be found at https://github.com/github/gitignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my `.gitignore` file at the current moment (SDK 10.1). Please keep in mind that as features are constantly being added/changed this file is subject to change accordingly.

```
arm/
x86
.settings/
*~
config.pri
.device
assets/.assets.index
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I've put a great deal of effort into it, but I have been using:

```
*.o
*.a
*.bar
.preview*
.moc
.obj
<projectname>
arm/Makefile
arm/Makefile.Debug
arm/Makefile.Release
x86/Makefile
x86/Makefile.Debug
x86/Makefile.Release
```

Where  is the name of the project. The IDE creates a file with that name that you don't need in the repo.

Answer (score 1):

This is my gitignore for single bb10 project (not for workspace)

```
# Compiled Object files
*.slo
*.lo
*.o

# Compiled Dynamic libraries
*.so

# Compiled Static libraries
*.lai
*.la
*.a

/.settings/
/.device
/config.pri
/arm/
/x86/
assets/.preview*
assets/.assets.index
```